# Excel VBA Scraping - Morningstar

Tags: vba, excel, scrape

I want to scape the financials on this link with an excel vba code , however unable to do this with my current code.

All I want to copy and paste the all of the data. It doesn't matter if it containes other information or not.

How can I do this?

Link:http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=SPN&region=usa&culture=en-US
Sub MS()

Sheets("Morningstar").ClearContents
    my_Page = "http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=SPN&region=usa&culture=en-US"

```
Sub MS()

Sheets("Morningstar").ClearContents
    my_Page = "http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html t=SPN&region=usa&culture=en-US"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_Page
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

   Application.EnableEvents = False
   IE.ExecWB 17, 0
   Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
   IE.ExecWB 12, 2
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
   Range("A1").Select

   IE.Quit
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=SPN&region=usa&culture=en-US

Comment: Could you add to your question your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the MSHTML library (you will need to enable this in references).

Load the html document into a object. IE.document
Loop through the elements to extract the data you want.

Here are some good examples of parsing the information using VBA. You can use these techniques to get your data:
[Parse HTML content in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488687/parse-html-content-in-vba)
[Pulling a table out of a mess of HTML w/ VBA & Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535180/pulling-a-table-out-of-a-mess-of-html-w-vba-excel)
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184695

Good luck. Remember to review regularly as site changes can break scraping code.